# Why does the Standard Library for C++ not contain hash table implementations?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, data-structures

I was reading over my text book `Data Structures and Algorithms: By Mark Allen Weiss` and it says that the standard library does not contain hash table implementations of a set or map, but rather compilers can provide hash_set and hash_map with same member functions of the set and map class. Why not just include hash implementations in the standard library? The book was published in 2006, have there been any revisions of C++ since to add these implementations to the standard library?

Comment: I know Mark personally great guy :D, most likely they're not included in the library because they would only be internally used. Also easier for the compiler to optimize them.

Comment: what do you mean by only be internally used? and that's pretty awesome, where do you know him from?

Comment: He's one of the head people at the school I attend. And by internal use I mean they are probably optimized for library specific code. And Nicolas may have a point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're looking for are called `std::unordered_set/map`. These are part of [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), the next version of the C++ standard (due to be finalized in a few months). They were also made available in Technical Report 1 in 2005, which was a list of additions to the C++ standard library between the first standard and the next one. In TR1, they were in the `std::tr1` namespace.

Boost actually ships an [implementation of TR1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_tr1.html) (though you shouldn't use the `std::tr1::shared_ptr` version, as the regular `boost::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` in C++11 are much, much better).

If I recall, the reason why hash tables were not initially introduced in C++98 was simply a lack of time for the C++ standards committee. They basically had a cut-off date in order to ship the thing, and hash tables didn't make it.

Comment: These were also available as TR1 library extensions since 2005.

Comment: well that's kind of unfortunate. But thanks! From wikipedia: "Including hash tables (unordered associative containers) in the C++ standard library is one of the most recurring requests. "

Comment: @Blastfurnace, yeah that would have been my next question. Something like an extension or update to include them

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Make that an answer, not just a comment.  TR1 is standard.

Comment: @tehman: [Standard C++ Library TR1 Extensions like `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982198%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) are already included in Visual Studio 2008.